# SQLite: Order by number of NULL values

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, sql-null

In SQLite, is there any way of ordering by the number of NULL values in each row, without having stored this number explicitly in a separate column?

Something like

```
SELECT rowid FROM
    (SELECT rowid, COUNT_NULLS(column_1,column_2,...,column_n) AS num_nulls FROM rows)
ORDER BY num_nulls;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of `null` values in the row in the `order by` clause, like so:

```
select *
from mytable t
order by (column_1 is null) + (column_2 is null) + ... (column_n is null)
```

Condition `(column_1 is null)` evaluates as `1` if the column is `null`, else `0`.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is that you'd have to type every column in the query?

Comment: @RadioControlled: yes, one way or another you need to enumerate the columns.

Comment: but this is not a problem